# Border points from point set

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I have an unordered set of two dimensional points, being the result of a image segmentation. The points when drawn together in a bitmap are a contigous region.

I'd like to know which points are in it's (region) border. The region might be concave, so this has ruled out [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to me. It also may have "holes" in it (ie. internal and external borders).

There's a good (> 10k) number of points. I tought about using a (non recursive) floodfill like search, adding the border points to a vector. This would also create me a problem to "separate" internal and external border points, if a internal border exists. Is there a better algorithm?

Comment: To answer your question one has to know how the border is defined. If you have, e.g., 4 points at the corners of a square and one point at the center, this center point could belong to the border or not, according to the definition of border point.

Comment: @Reinhard Männer Since it's just a visualization issue to me, I'm open to different definitions (a pixel here or there makes no pratical visual difference in a large image). But for an answer, every single point that has a neighbor outside the point set, can be said to be a border point.

Comment: @VitorBraga, there's no good definition for "neighbor" either. I think that for any set of points you can generate, there will be a border that includes every single point. Your problem needs to be better defined than that.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Maybe I should have said "pixel" instead of point. All points are in a discrete grid. A neighbor is any point with a difference of 1 unit in any X or/and Y coordinate.

Comment: Have you looked at alpha hull algorithms? Similar to convex hull, but can accommodate concavity. Would you be able to post a sample image?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is more complex than it seems. It is very nicely described in the link below, unfortunately without an algorithm. I hope this helps a little.
http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geosensor.net%2Fpapers%2Fgalton06.GISCIENCE.ppt&ei=s4xdUf_BMqT-4QSmrICADw&usg=AFQjCNHKBdBDxQt9G29_l2QW2yd-AxRXXQ&bvm=bv.44770516,d.bGE

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be complex. I'll follow the link and read it. If I'm able to get something done, I'll post an update. Thank you, Professor Männer.